# How can I calculate the angle

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

I'm creating a game where if the enemy is in a certain range and is in front of the player the player can attack the enemy. I have worked out the radius distance and made it facing forward depending in which way the player faces but how can i create the angle so it makes like a cone shape from the player. I have got an image. The thin green line is the radius which I have worked out but how can i calculate the red cone.

Here is the image for more better understanding

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28v63h0&s=6

This is what I done so far

package

```
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {

        var radius:Number = 60;

        public function Player()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
        }   

        function Update(event:Event)
        {       
            var radiusx:Number = x+radius*Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI);
            var radiusy:Number = y+radius*Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI);

            // Rotate to mouse;
            var dx = parent.mouseX - x;
            var dy = parent.mouseY - y;
            var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
            rotation = angle;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the definition of tangent:

```
tan(a/2) = s/(2d)
```

where `s` is size (diamerer) of the enemy and `d` is the shortest distance to the enemy. Here `a` is the total visible angle (between two red lines).

Comment: @ sashkello Thanks for the reply but I can't seem to fit it in with my coding. Do you mind showing me how I can do that in codes to fit my game.

Comment: I've no idea what you are actually trying to achieve. Your question asked about calculating the angle and this is how you can do it. Sorry, can't be of any more help

Comment: @ Sashkello: Thats fine now I know exactly what I'm was looking for. I was looking for line of sight of the player but I've seen many tutorials based on line of sight so i just need to check them out, thanks anyway